# Regular expression for containing DD-MMM-YYYY or DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM

Tags: validation, date, format, expression

I have been googling about and need a valid regular expression statement (which begins and ends with the same character) which will validate for DD-MMM-YYYY or DD-MMM-YYYY HH:SS.

It does not matter about checking for valid dates (such as 31-Feb-2013 would be OK) it is just the formatting I require.

For example:

- 99-ZzZ-9999 would be valid.
- 99-ZzZ-9999 23:59 would be valid.
- 99-ZzZ-99 would be NOT be valid.
- 1-feb-2013 would NOT be valid
- 01-Feb-2013 would be valid.
- 30-Feb-2013 would be valid.
- 30-Feb-2013 12:59am would NOT be valid.

The checking for valid dates is done elsewhere but this is just for a formatting prompt.

I've done a search but i can't seem to find one with an opation time section like i need and where the regex starts and ends with the same characters to not cause an error.

Thanks,

Comment: regex which `which begins and ends with the same character`!

Comment: Yes for example ^([0-2]\d|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}$ works normally in javascript but in PHP the preg_match will report a notice: NOTICE: No ending delimiter '^' found. Read documentation how to format $pattern.

Answer (score 1):

for `DD-MMM-YYYY` you can use this regex `^[01][0-9]-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}$`

Example:http://www.regexr.com/3bdeu

Comment: 99-ZzZ-9999 23:59 would be valid, as requested by the OP, so this doesn't really answer the question...